# Peak Current in a transmission line

Tags: power-electronics, electromagnetism, transmission-line, power-engineering, microwave

Let's consider a transmission line (which drives a generic load ZL) connected to an AC voltage source.

If we know that the peak voltage of the source is equal to Vp, how can we evaluate the peak current (is it Vp/Z0? Vp/Zin?)? Moreover, is it possible to evaluate the peak power by knowing only the peak voltage and current?

Comment: You want the peak current that the source needs to provide, or the peak current at any point in the standing wave on the line?

Comment: Only the peak current that the source needs to provide

Comment: Can't you calculate the peak current of the load? and that is the same current through the line?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the input impedance of a transmission line terminated with a mismatched load? (If not, try some research. This is covered on many websites and in any textbook covering transmission lines)

Comment: Peak current depends on the condition. E.g. Reconnect with saturation current in magnetics is significant,  faults currents are also significant, yet line loss is designed to be < 5% for distribution when no compensation is applied for load variations on networks with integrity.

Comment: Is it correct to calculate Ipeak as Vpeak/Zin, and POWERpeak = Vpeak × Ipeak?